# Cronjob is running every minute but not at a specific time

Tags: cron, timezone

The job works if set like this:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/test/cron/test.php
```

And if set to something like:

```
15 20 * * * /usr/bin/php /home/test/cron/test.php
```

it's not working.

```
[root@localhost mail]# uname -or
2.6.18-308.el5 GNU/Linux
[root@localhost mail]# cat /etc/*elease
#CentOS release 5.8 (Final)
redhat-4
```

I don't know if this going to help but when I do this:

```
[root@localhost mail]# date
 Wed Aug  5 20:54:02 KST 2015
```

and when an email comes the date is displayed like so:

```
Wed Aug  5 06:51:01 2015
```

which is actually one hour behind the time. 
The date was showing up `EDT` instead of `KST`, so I changed `etc/profile` but the cron job still wouldn't work.

Comment: first read the man page for cron. Because the second option means: at 20.15 of everyday run the job.

Comment: When/how often do you want the cronjob to take place? The cron syntax is `Min Hour Day Month 'Day of Week'` see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Examples

Comment: I want to run at noon, but since I can't wait one day to test I set to something like 5 minutes in the future. it's correct in this example i was trying to run it at 20:15 KST everyday. Do you have any ideas what maybe the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating `/etc/localtime` for the system wide time zone setting might fix your problem.  I guess `KST` stands for Korea Standard Time, so you might want to choose `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Seoul` for it.  You can also run `tzselect` to know which file in `/usr/share/zoneinfo` to choose.

```
$ sudo cp /etc/localtime /etc/localtime.orig # for backup
$ sudo cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Seoul /etc/localtime
$ date
Wed Aug  5 21:50:23 KST 2015
```

Then restart `cron`, or reboot your server.

Comment: Thank you very much Yaegashi ^_^. It was exactly the problem. You should go and answer dozens of other similar questions and collect the loot :).